# Compute $T([-1, 4, 2])$ given the effect of three vectors on a $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this that $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and these results of the linear transformation:

$T\left (  \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}\right )=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\1\end{bmatrix}$

$T\left (  \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}\right )=\begin{bmatrix}4\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

$T\left (  \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
-1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}\right )=\begin{bmatrix}3\\-5\end{bmatrix}$

And I need to find $T([-1, 4, 2])$.

This is my solution:

Write a vector $\vec{b}$ in terms of the three transformed $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ vectors:

$\vec{b}=\begin{bmatrix}b_{1}\\b_{2}\\b_{3}\end{bmatrix}=k_{1}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}+k_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}+k_{3}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
-1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Then,

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & b_{1}\\ 
0 & 1 & -1 & b_{2}\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}

Reducing the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & b_{1}\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & b_{2} + b_{3}\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}

So any $\vec{b}$ with the linear transformation can be written as:

$T\left (  \begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\ 
b_{2}\\ 
b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}\right )=b_{1}T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \right )+(b_{2}+b_{3})T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} \right )+b_{3}T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix} \right )$

With this result I can calculate $T([-1, 4, 2])$:

$T\left (  \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
4\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix}\right )=-1T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \right )+(4+2)T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} \right )+2T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix} \right )=\begin{bmatrix}33\\-17\end{bmatrix}$

Is my result correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your result is correct.  You can find it easily noting that:
$$
[-1,4,2]=-1[1,0,0]+6[0,1,0]+2[0,-1,1]
$$
so, by linearity:
$$
T[-1,4,2]=-[-3,1]+6[4,-1]+2[3,-5]
$$